# Difference between rsop.msc results and gpresult /v group policy being applied

Tags: group-policy

I have applied a GPO to a series of computers on a test network. It applies fine except on one Vista machine that is ignoring it.

The only setting in the GPO is to set Allow Inbound Remote Administration = Enabled

On the Vista system, I opened rsop.msc and looked in Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Network -> Network Connections -> Windows Firewall -> Domain Profile (and standard), and the State is Enabled, the GPO name is 'Default Domain Policy'

If I then go into CMD and enter `gpresult /v`, and the results give a USER SETTINGS section only, not a COMPUTER SETTINGS section, so I cannot see what the status is for the GPOs as they affect computers, as I can all other systems. Also `netsh firewall show state` indicates that:

```
Profile = Domain
Group Policy Version = Windows Firewall
Remote Admin Mode = Disable
no ports open
```

The GPO is linked to the a.local domain (my domain) in Group Policy Management, so I cannot guess what is wrong.

Should they be agreeing with each other? Why would it not apply in this case? Why is there no COMPUTER SETTINGS in the `gpresult /v` output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run the gpresult with an account that has local admin rights from an elevated command prompt to see the computer settings in gpresult /v.